# Select statement with array is throwing error

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

This statement is throwing error:

```
FOR _i2 IN 1 .. array_upper(p_extra_info, 1) LOOP
    ....
    SELECT currval('ad_extra_info_id_seq') INTO _new_extra_info_ids[_i2];
    ....
END LOOP;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 179: ...rrval('ad_extra_info_id_seq') INTO _new_extra_info_ids[_i2];
                                                                   ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "["
SQL state: 42601
Character: 7907
```

Variable `_new_extra_info_ids` is declared like this: `_new_extra_info_ids integer[];`

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Firstly one recommendation Please do not declare any variable name starting with special Character some times I faced the compiler get confused with this kind of naming convention.

Comment: I put '_' in front of all declared variables for distinction - never given me trouble. @a_horse_with_no_name that works, thanks.

Comment: Doing stuff like that in loops _might_ indicate some inefficient handling of sets in your function. You might want to revisit that logic - but there is not enough information to really say that. But seeing a `select` inside a loop usually rings an alarm bell for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a direct assignment instead of a select:

```
FOR _i2 IN 1 .. array_upper(p_extra_info, 1) LOOP
    ....
    _new_extra_info_ids[_i2] := currval('ad_extra_info_id_seq');
    ....
END LOOP;
```